# Change file extension to .zip and unzip file from document folder

Tags: ios, swift, zip

Using Alamofire for downloading. File is being downloaded in app document folder, in attachment, there is .hub file. 
I need to change .hub file to .zip than i need to unzip this file for audio file.
Code for downloading ->

```
func getAudioFileFromServer(url: String, uuid: String) {

    let fileURL = URL(string: url)
    var request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)
    request.setValue("myapikey", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-api-key")
    let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination()
    Alamofire.download(request, to: destination).validate().responseData { response in
        debugPrint(response)
        print(response.destinationURL!)
     }
}
```

Response from server ->

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FC5F17C4-E8D3-4406-926A-97EB9447D87B/Documents/'bac6151ffbe74140a31408938c91fa33.hub'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading the file change the extension to .zip with "saveFileInDirectory" method and with success block we can get the main file.

```
 self.saveFileInDirectory(data: responce.result.value, fileName: "\(name!).zip", successblock: { (path) in
            print(path!)
            var filepath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath)
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: url, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                let done = SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: path!, toDestination: url.path)
                if done{
                    let items = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: url.path)
                    print(items)
                    let destinationUrl = url.appendingPathComponent(items[0])
                    print(destinationUrl)
                }
            } catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
        })


func saveFileInDirectory(data: Data?, fileName: String?, successblock: @escaping (_ path: String?) -> Void) { // To add the image to cache for given identifier.
      let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( .documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
      let path = paths.appending("/\(fileName!)")
         if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path)) {
    try! FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: path)
         } else {
    do {
        try data?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path, isDirectory: false))
        successblock(path)
    } catch {
        successblock(nil)
        print("Error while caching the data in cache folder.")
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To rename a file, use the function `moveItem(atPath:toPath:)` of `FileManager`

To unzip, the easiest way would be to integrate some zip library: https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive or https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip

Comment: Getting error 
“'MyFile.hub'” couldn’t be moved to “Documents” because either the former doesn’t exist, or the folder containing the latter doesn’t exist.
My code is ->

    let zipPath = response.destinationURL?.deletingPathExtension()
    let fileName = zipPath?.lastPathComponen
    let fileNameZip = zipPath?.appendingPathExtension("zip")
     do {
          try FileManager.default.moveItem(atPath: (response.destinationURL?.absoluteString)!, toPath: (fileNameZip?.absoluteString)!)
      print("Done"
}
      catch {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
     }

Comment: Please check (a) if file at source exists (using `FileManager.default.fileExists`) and (b) if the destination does _not_ exist. Maybe (c) you also need to get rid of the single quotations in the file name (`'MyFile.hub'` instead of `MyFile.hub`)

Comment: Please help with unzip , i am using https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip to unzip file 

            let dummyAddres = response.destinationURL
            let zipPath = dummyAddres?.deletingPathExtension()
            let fileNameZip = zipPath?.appendingPathExtension("zip")
do {
    let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileNameZip, withExtension: "zip")!
    let unzipDirectory = try Zip.quickUnzipFile(filePath) // Unzip
}
catch {
  print("Something went wrong")
}

Comment: Please update the question above with your unzip code, because in the comments it's hard to read. What is not working? Do you get "Something went wrong"? In this case, try to get a more specific error, like `/* ... */ } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error:\(error)")
        }`